# Introductory books in the public domain

Tags: open-access, translations

I came across several collections that are of great interest to me: they are books that summarize the knowledge of a specific field in about a hundred pages. There is, for example, the "Que sais-je?" collection in France or Oxford's "Very Short Introductions".

I was wondering if an equivalent project existed under an open source license to freely translate and distribute the texts.

*There is no commercial intent.*

Comment: Are you asking about a project to translate and distribute those *specific* copyrighted texts (which would be illegal, whether commercial or not), or a project to write, from scratch, texts of a similar sort?

Comment: I am looking for translating similar texts but which are under a permissive licence.

Comment: Isn't that basically Wikipedia?

Comment: Wikipedia is always changing and article are much shorter than the books I mentionned.

Comment: Some textbooks are freely downloadable. http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/ is an example

Answer (score 3):

What your looking for looks a lot like the **wikimedia project [wikibooks.org](https://www.wikibooks.org/).**

Here a quote from the main page :

> Welcome to Wikibooks,
>
> the open-content textbooks collection that anyone can edit.
>
> 3,072 books with 83,999 pages

Also there are a lot of **old textbooks in the public domain** published in different languages. One repository of such books is [project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/), where I find the category page helpful to get books in the right context/science.

Also some books, event recent ones are published with a open licence and as such you are allowed to read, copy and translate them at will, such books are for example published by [framabooks](https://framabook.org/) (mostly in french).

These are must have books and there are some others to be found.

Also some book are freely readable online, copyright holder being aware, eg see [VMLS](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/vmls/) if interested in maths or [Motion Mountain](http://www.motionmountain.net/index.html) for physics, but a big mouthful, not just 100 pages.  (not sure for the licence, couldn't check it).

These are more often than not typeset in latex... So you might also ask on the author for the sources.

(I hope this answer isn't too much out of the context of the question)

Answer (score 0):

Some textbooks are freely downloadable. http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/ is an example

You could also be interested in [Creative Commons Licenses](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/).